# Why does my ProcessBuilder inputStream result in different data than from linux command line

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder

When I run the following command from my Ubuntu 18.4 command line:

```
sudo ./nuvgpio 47 1 > gpioresult-47.txt
```

The resulting file has the following data:

```
Try 4E
ChipID_Hi=0xD2, ChipID_Lo=0x82.
2, GP48, data=0x00
```

When I run the process from Java, the result stream does not contain the last line.

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Run a command  line program (nuvgpio) to read/write the status of GPIO pins on a Jetway SBC.
 */
public class JetwayIODriver {

    private static int LED_PIN_NUMBER = 40;
    private static int COVER_PIN_NUMBER = 42;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            String directoryStr = "/home/tester2/IdeaProjects/automation-framework/device-common-parent/device-io/src/";
            File dir = new File(directoryStr);

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            builder.directory(dir);
            builder.redirectErrorStream();
            int mode = 1;   // 1=read, 0=write
            builder.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo 'tester2' | sudo -S ./nuvgpio", Integer.toString(COVER_PIN_NUMBER), Integer.toString(mode));

            Process process = builder.start();
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
            }

            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            input.close();
            System.out.println(String.format("GPIO process finished with exit code : %s", exitCode));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Output from Java:

```
Stdout: Try 4E
Stdout: ChipID_Hi=0xD2, ChipID_Lo=0x82.
GPIO process finished with exit code : 0
```

One odd thing of note: When I run from the command line and output to the console, the 3rd line of text is on the same line as the new prompt:
[image]

The nuvgpio program seems to be not putting a line break at the end.  Could this be the cause and if so, can I inject one into the process output?

Comment: You didn't say your OS.  It's probably that the final line isn't newline terminated, so stdout line buffering is swallowing it.  If you can change nuvgpio, then do so. If not, you'll need to arrange for its stdout to be unbuffered. Off hand, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, the input is probably being lost because readLine() requires the newline.  It's not seeing a full line, so it's returning null, and you're quitting too early. Try reading lines until seeing null, then read the final output one character at a time with read(). Scanner might work as well.

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.  I tried reading characters in the while loop... e.g. while((charInt = reader.read()) > =0) ... and that also did not have the characters from the 3rd line in the stream.